# Node.js working fine, unless with localhost directly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, localhost

I've been at it for hours, can't seem to shake off this error.

`socket.io-1.0.3.js:2 GET https://localhost:2000/socket.io/EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1483313078894-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

My node.js server works good when I log in from alternative sites, but when I try with localhost, this is the error I get. Before this, I kept getting an "https" error, so I added "https" on all links.

Client HTML localhost

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.3.js"></script>`

Client Javascript localhost

`var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:2000');`

Just to be more clear, I'm trying to move my website from web host to my private localhost. Everything works great from web host, but getting errors from localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before this, I kept getting an "https" error, so I added "https" on all links.

It's not enough to just use HTTPS URLs... your server also has to be listening for HTTPS connections.

If you must use HTTPS, you need to set your server up to listen on a different port than regular HTTP (usually HTTPS is on `:443`), and configure a certificate and key.  You can use self-signed certificates for local testing, but you must get a real certificate (such as using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), or a paid service) to use this for the rest of the world.

Comment: As an additional complication: No CA in the world will give anyone an SSL certificate for the name `localhost`. If secure connections to the local host are needed, a certificate must be acquired for a regular hostname that resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into it now
@Tomalak Would a public IP work?

Comment: The vast majority of certificates are issued for a FQDN (e.g. www.example.com) not an IP address. The browser checks the name in the certificate exactly matches the name in the URL, so if the URL says https://blah.example.com/something/something the certificate needs to include the name blah.example.com. If you get a certificate for an IP address (not recommended) you need to put the IP address in the URL for it to work.

Certificate issuers don't care what IP address the name they're issuing for has, just that you really control that name. Proving control may be easier with a public IP.

Comment: @tery.blargh I am not talking about IP addresses. Before you waste any more time on this matter, think if you really need a HTTP**S** connection to localhost. This is probably more trouble than it's worth. Use HTTP.

Comment: This is such a headache and confusing >_< I tried changing the port from 443 to something else, but the "https" is grayed out and I can't change :/ Do I really have to have an SSL?

Comment: @Tomalak I tried to change the Type in Bindings from https to http, but it's grayed out :(

Comment: Nevermind, I figured how to do it. Thanks guys, works with http! :)